# how to read .SDL text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .SDL Text file in format

```
244455|199|6577888|20210401|138.61|0.78|83.16|0.00|0.00|221.77|6|0.00|17000
```

is there any python library to read and interpret such .SDL text file?

Comment: What output are you expecting? Have you tried `import csv`?

Comment: more specifically, many CSV libraries (including [the builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)) allow setting the separator to something other than `","`, `"|"` in your case

Comment: No, I haven't tried using csv because the delimiter is not constant. Here is another example of the format of the .SDL file
490797|C|64||BLAH BLAH BLAH||||0|190/0000/07|A|1998889|198666566|||8990900|BLAGHHH72|L78899|||0040|012|432565|012|435659||MBLAHAHAHAHASIE|2WES|ARGHKKHHHT|PRE||0002|012|432565|012|435659||MR. JOHN DOE|PO BOX 198898|SILUHHHHH||0052|661|13||82110|35000000|2|0|||||0|0||||Y||70877746414|R

Comment: What is a "SDL" file? Can you point us to some documentation?

Comment: @OhiaGeorge the delimiter _does_ appears to be the same there, presumably `||` represents an empty column in that row!

Comment: @ti7 thanks for your answer. However, in some places, i see occurrences like this ||||||||||0||0||  ,  |C|64|| ,  CC||||0|

This gives me the impression I need some kind special tool or library to interpret the file

Comment: certainly, which is why tools write files! what is your expected result?

Comment: I want each row as python list

Comment: You need to know what those data mean... SDL may be the old Microsoft's Service Description Language, or Autodesk's Scene Description Language, or a few other things. But in the end, if you want to know whether your file is basically a CSV with a "|" separarator just check if each line has the same number of occurrences of "|"

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that there will be no multiple line in the file.

**data.sdl**

> 490797|C|64||BLAH BLAH BLAH||||0|190/0000/07|A|1998889|198666566|||8990900|BLAGHHH72|L78899|||0040|012|432565|012|435659||MBLAHAHAHAHASIE|2WES|ARGHKKHHHT|PRE||0002|012|432565|012|435659||MR. JOHN DOE|PO BOX 198898|SILUHHHHH||0052|661|13||82110|35000000|2|0|||||0|0||||Y||70877746414|R

**Python script to extract data in a list:**

```
data_list = []

# with open('path/to/file.sdl') as file

with open('data.sdl', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

data_list = data.split('|')
data_list[-1] = data_list[-1].strip()
data_list = list(filter(None, data_list))
```

**Output:**

```
['490797', 'C', '64', 'BLAH BLAH BLAH', '0', '190/0000/07', 'A', '1998889', '198666566', '8990900', 'BLAGHHH72', 'L78899', '0040', '012', '432565', '012', '435659', 'MBLAHAHAHAHASIE', '2WES', 'ARGHKKHHHT', 'PRE', '0002', '012', '432565', '012', '435659', 'MR. JOHN DOE', 'PO BOX 198898', 'SILUHHHHH', '0052', '661', '13', '82110', '35000000', '2', '0', '0', '0', 'Y', '70877746414', 'R']
```

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming there's more rows than you've provided in the same format, Pandas [`.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) will be able to load this up for you!

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("my_path/whateverfilename.sdl", sep="|")
```

This will create a [DataFrame object](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for you, which may be what you're after

If you just wanted each row as a list, you can simply load the file and `.split()` each line, though this will probably be harder to work with overall

```py
split_lines = []
with open("my_path/whateverfilename.sdl") as fh:
    for line in fh:  # file-like objects are iterable by-line
        split_lines.append(line.split("|"))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, in some places, i see occurrences like this ||||||||||0||0|| , |C|64|| , CC||||0| This gives me the impression I need some kind special tool or library to interpret the file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each line as the same amount of columns:

**File** `'./path_to_data'`:

```
244455|199|6577888|20210401|138.61|0.78|83.16|0.00|0.00|221.77|6|0.00|17000
||||0||0|| , |C|64||
```

**Data "reader"**:

```
import numpy as np

path = './path_to_data'

N_COLS = 13

# declare the data type of each column - in this case python Object
dts = np.dtype(', '.join(['O'] * N_COLS))

data = np.loadtxt(fname=path, delimiter='|', dtype=dts, unpack=False, skiprows=0, max_rows=None)

for i in data:
    print(i)
```

Output

```
('244455', '199', '6577888', '20210401', '138.61', '0.78', '83.16', '0.00', '0.00', '221.77', '6', '0.00', '17000')
('', '', '', '', '0', '', '0', '', ' , ', 'C', '64', '', '')
```

To get the data as column: `unpack=True`

Tell form which line start to read `skiprows=0`

End reading at line `max_rows=None` if `None` read everything (default).

Here the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Comment: @Ohia George How are stored your data in the file? Lines of inhomogeneous length? How should you handle the empty string? Output as strings?